# Restrict Azure Web API to Just API Manager

Tags: rest, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying RESTful API's in Azure and protecting them with teh Azure API Manager.  However, I've not been able to figure out how to restrict calls to the actual API to block requests going around the API manager.  Is there a way in the web.config or something to restrict IP's, domain names.... on teh .net web api?

Answer (score 1):

You can whitelist the IPs in c# code. Check below link for code changes,
https://weblogs.asp.net/senthil/restrict-ip-address-in-asp-net-web-api

You can get the static IP address of APIM in overview section. But you have to consider below points,

In all tiers of API Management, the public IP address (VIP) of the API Management tenant is static for the lifetime of the tenant, with some exceptions. The IP address changes in these circumstances:

1. The service is deleted and then re-created.
2. The service subscription is suspended or warned (for example, for
   nonpayment) and then reinstated.
3. You add or remove Azure Virtual Network (you can use Virtual Network
   only at the Developer and Premium tier).

For multi-region deployments, the regional address changes if the region is vacated and then reinstated (you can use multi-region deployment only at the Premium tier).

Premium tier tenants that are configured for multi-region deployment are assigned one public IP address per region.

You can get your IP address (or addresses, in a multi-region deployment) on the tenant page in the Azure portal.

Comment: Even you can restict IPs on Azure app service level without any code changes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure call limits and quota policies through the API Management Portal, including inbound and outbound policies. Below is the policy template, you can choose what you want. Here **Restrict caller IPs** would meet your requirements.
[image]

For detailed configuration, please check [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-product-with-rules/#policies) and follow the steps.